# "And another X" or and "another X one"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Is the one necessary in cases like these?

Example sentence:

> The machine had a lumpy side and another flat (one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Another" is a determiner of difference so you need a noun or noun phrase to follow.  "Flat" is presumably an adjective (assuming you are not describing something like a flat tire---often referred to as a "flat") so you need the "one" to follow.  However, if you did have a noun following the "another" you could say:
"The machine had a lumpy slide and another widget."